# Android intent via notification not keeping extra data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

I'm trying to pass a String via an intent stored in a notification.
But when I get the String out of the intent in the new fragment, it's a null and it gives me a NullPointerException.

Code to create notification (in method A of fragment A in activity A)

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("My first notification");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Click to see the details...");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        //Intent maken voor notification
        Intent intentVoorNotificatie = new Intent(getActivity(), activity_detail_notification.class);
        EditText edTekst = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etTekst);


        String strTekstNotificatie = edTekst.getText().toString();
        intentVoorNotificatie.putExtra("detailNotificatie", strTekstNotificatie);


        //Intent naar PendingIntent converteren
        PendingIntent pIntentVootNotificatie = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                                0, intentVoorNotificatie, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntentVootNotificatie);

        //Notificatie tonen
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
```

Method A of fragment B in activity B

```
//Haal doorgegeven tekst uit intent
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String strTekst = intent.getStringExtra("detailNotificatie");

    TextView tvTekst = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvDetailVanNotificatie);
    tvTekst.setText(strTekst);
```

I get the nullPointer on the `setText()` method due to the String being empty when extracting it from the intent.

Did I do something wrong for data to get lost or dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code `

```
 PendingIntent pIntentVootNotificatie = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                                0, intentVoorNotificatie, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

to this `

```
PendingIntent pIntentVootNotificatie = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                                0, intentVoorNotificatie, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: That didn't work, but I've found the source of the problem. When I get my TextView from my design, it doesn't seem to work. It's still equal to null and that's why the SetText() method doesn't work. Now trying to figure out why it gives me a null